# How to use icons into the main Applications menu

Tags: icons, appmenu

I use Ubuntu Studio 16.04 LTS.

I know how to modify/eliminate/add elements into the main Applications Menu (the most similar Windows [START] button we have into Ubuntu), but I was failed about to put some icons into any new element I want to put/change.

When I click on the "Properties" button of the element, I can click on the Icon button, but... The system doesn't give me some Icon directory, folder and/or palette (as we have when we create a new desktop link). Not, in this main Apps menu there is not any icon place where we could choose an icon.

So... How can I change/put icons into the elements of this main Apps menu?

Comment: Right-click somewhere on the empty desktop. Application-menu pops up. Choose the item you want to change with another right-click. The `Edit Launcher`-window pops up. Left-click on `Icon`, `Select an Icon`-window pops up. Does this help?

Answer (score 1):

To create or modify the .desktop files for applications and scripts, you can use **Arronax**. It will allow use to change icons. It will also allow you to create .desktop files from scratch.

To install it, use Synaptic. Start Synaptic from the dashboard. Click the RELOAD icon, then the SEARCH icon, then enter `arronax`, you'll see three results, mark them all of installation, then click the APPLY icon.

[image]

**update**: if it's not in your Synaptic, you can go directly to the website http://www.florian-diesch.de/software/arronax/ to get it.

Comment: Synaptic doesn't show any package with that name "Arronax". Also Ubuntu Software Center doesn't show the package.

Comment: @Juan please see my update which contains a direct link for Arronax

Answer (score 1):

EUREKA!

I found the solution.

You just have to open the Main Configuration Manager panel and choose "Menu Editor" option.

Into that subpanel you have all the tools to create, modify and erase the elements from all the Apps menu-es.

So simple and effective.

That's all, folks!!!