# How to add a Jupyter Notebook icon to my app menu?

Tags: python, launcher, jupyter

I am working on Jupyter Notebook and I want to see its icon in the Applications menu, but it is not there. I should also mention that I do not have Anaconda, and I installed Jupyter separately.
Also its location is:

```
~/.local/bin/jupyter-notebook
```

I run this for using Jupyter every time.

Comment: See: [How to use icons into the main Applications menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/838035/how-to-use-icons-into-the-main-applications-menu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a Jupyter Notebook launcher to start a Jupyter notebook from the applications menu do the following:

1. Create a `jupyter-notebook.desktop` file in `~/.local/share/applications`:

   ```
   touch ~/.local/share/applications/jupyter-notebook.desktop
   ```
2. Open the file with a text editor (I'm using `nano`):

   ```
   nano ~/.local/share/applications/jupyter-notebook.desktop
   ```
3. Add the following to the file:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Comment=Open a Jupyter Notebook in your browser
   Terminal=false
   Name=JupyterNotebook
   Exec="/full/path/to/jupyter-notebook"
   Icon="/full/path/to/custom/icon"
   Type=Application
   ```

   Note that in the `Exec` and `Icon` fields you have to use the full path to `jupyter-notebook` and the custom icon you want to use for the launcher. So in your case you should add something like `/home/user/.local/bin/jupyter-notebook` instead of `~/.local/bin/jupyter-notebook` in `Exec`, where `user` is your actual username. Similarly for `Icon`.
4. Save and close the file (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> in `nano`).

That's it! You should now be able to run Jupyter Notebook from your applications menu.

---

**Note:** Every time you open a Jupyter Notebook this way, a new Jupyter server will be launched as well, although without being shown in a terminal. If you close the browser tab that Jupyter Notebook runs in, the server will continue to run. So you'll have to close the server yourself. To do that you can use the `jupyter notebook list` command in a terminal, which will list all running servers, and then you'll have tot use `jupyter notebook stop port`, where `port` is the port that localhost runs on.

For example, I have started three Jupyter Notebooks using the applications menu launcher and I have closed the browser tabs. `jupyter notebook list` shows:

```
Currently running servers:
http://localhost:8889/?token=23b2468a3229ca7a18430cd48039fd95e0e6866d2a8cd5d5 :: /home/user
http://localhost:8888/?token=406937f75d9e564986d0e1c7929a9119c95eeff01b5bcca8 :: /home/user
http://localhost:8890/?token=2fa24c5385fe7dc4d0fc91cf267cff029571614e272f8453 :: /home/user
```

To close them I have to run:

```
jupyter notebook stop 8889
jupyter notebook stop 8888
jupyter notebook stop 8890
```

Comment: Thank you, it completely solved my problem, and I have two questions: what does the %f sign mean and is it possible to change my app logo?

Comment: `%f` is used as a placeholder for a filename in the case, for example, you wish to open a file in a specific program by using right-click.  It is not really needed here, since you just want a launcher, and can be removed. I added it by mistake. To have a custom icon you can add a line below `Exec`: `Icon="/full/path/to/custom/icon"`. You can read more about `.desktop` files here: https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html

Comment: super thanks to you